# Using same content DB for two different farms

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2007, content-database, server-farm

I have two SP 2007 farms (APP + WFE + DB).

They are identical in terms of OS and SP build numbers. Every thing is same except of course they are using different machines names as they are part of same AD.

So farm 1 servers are called app1, wfe1 and db while farm 2 servers are called app2, wfe2, and db. Notice they are using same database sever although their config database names are different such as SharePoint_Config1 and SharePoint_Config2. So both farms share same database machine.

It is possible to use same content database for web application on those farms i.e. both web apps on those farms point to same content db?

Comment: what is your end goal, why you want same contentDB to two different farm?

Comment: The end goal is to create DR but you are right having one content db being shared by two farms doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generally do this, but the content will be read only in the second farm. This would be similar to creating a disaster recovery farm.

Comment: On second thought I think the scenario I posted doesn't make any sense. Because if the idea is to make a DR then it doesn't make sense to point both farms to same content DB because if that DB server goes down then everything will be down. So instead we should create a new db server, restore content db there and then do mirroring/replication.